# How to get JButton label text by actionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
 public Keypad() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
        for(int i=9; i>=0; i--){
            JButton tmp = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            add(tmp);
            tmp.addActionListener(this);
        }
        JButton btnPoint = new JButton(".");
        JButton btnEqual = new JButton("=");
        add(btnPoint);
        btnPoint.addActionListener(this);
        add(btnEqual);
        btnEqual.addActionListener(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getSource());
    }
```

As a beginner of JFrame, I try to create some JButton with for loop. However, I have no idea how to handle the actionPerformed by corresponding button as they have the same variable name "tmp", so `if(event.getSource() == tmp)` may not suitable for this case.

In the actionPerformed, I try to print out the source by clicking different button, the result is:  `javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,75x29,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=com.apple.laf.AquaButtonBorder$Dynamic@4be40942,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=2,bottom=0,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=9,defaultCapable=true]`

It seem that it can get the button label `text=9` correctly when I click button "9". so can I do something like `if(event.getSource().getText() == "9")` ?

Comment: The actual line looks like `if (((JButton) event.getSource()).getText().equals("9"))`  I'd separate the `event.getSource` from the `if` statement.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to handle the actionPerformed by corresponding button as they have the same variable name "tmp"

Actually the [scope](https://www.javatpoint.com/scope-of-variables-in-java) of `tmp` is the `for` loop in `Keypad` class constructor. Hence you can't refer to it in method `actionPerformed`.

You are assigning the same `ActionListener` to all your `JButton`s and you want a way to determine, in the `actionPerformed` method, which `JButton` was clicked. Since every `JButton` you create has a different text, your idea of getting the `JButton` text seems like one way to do this. So how can you get the text of the `JButton` that was clicked in your `actionPerformed` method?

A `JButton` has a [ButtonModel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html) which has an *action command* which is a string. By default, the text of the `JButton` is also its *action command*. The `ActionEvent`, i.e. the parameter of method `actionPerformed`, declares method [getActionCommand](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand()) which returns the *action command* of the `JButton` that was clicked. Hence the simplest way to get the text of the `JButton`, in your `actionPerformed` method, is to call method `getActionCommand` on the `actionPerformed` method parameter.

```java
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
    String buttonText = event.getActionCommand();
    switch (buttonText) {
        case "1":
            // Handle button "1".
            break;
        // Remaining cases...
    }
}
```

This Web page may also be helpful:
[How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Alternatively, you can assign a separate `ActionListener` to each `JButton`. Since Java 8, this is easily done using [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) because `ActionListener` is a functional interface.

```java
public Keypad() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
    for(int i=9; i>=0; i--){
        JButton tmp = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
        add(tmp);
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                tmp.addActionListener(this::handleButton1);
                break;
            // Remaining cases...
        }
        tmp.addActionListener(this);
    }
}

private void handleButton1(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
    // No need to check the "event" source since the source is always the same.
}
```

In order to be a valid method reference, method `handleButton1` must return the same value that method `actionPerformed` returns – which is `void` and it must have the same parameters as method `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation, the method 1 fix my issue perfectly =)